# Separate Chaining Implementation

Tags: java

I'm doing a project where I have to make my own hash table with separate chaining to keep track of the entries.

Is it absolutely necessary to use SinglyLinkedList to implement separate chaining or can I just create my constructor like this (considering I already have a separate Node class prepared).

```
Node[] arr;
private static final int TABLE_SIZE = 101;

public HashTable() {
    arr = new Node[TABLE_SIZE];
}
```

Comment: Does the Node class contain a pointer to the next Node?

Comment: @TheLostMind: sorry I'm not sure exactly what you mean by conflict conditions?
McLovin: yes! my Node class does contain a pointer to the next Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can declare it as an array of `Node`s.
A `SinglyLinkedList` is just a wrapper which contains some methods a reference to the first node of the list. With an array of nodes, you can simply iterate across them with your own methods to achieve the same functionality. For example, your find method might look something like this:

```
Node n = arr[obj.hashCode() % TABLE_SIZE];
while (n != null) {
    if(n.key.equals(obj)) return n.value;
    n = n.next;
}
return null;
```

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you so much! Just to make sure, to accomplish separate chaining, I can still approach it by declaring it as an array of Nodes correct?

Comment: @KoreanGhost - I don't think so.. What *would* be the size of the node array?. arrays have fixed size.. How can you accomodate more elements if `conflict for same key` > `size of node[]`?

Comment: @TheLostMind Oh shoot, okay, I'm just trying to figure out if its still considered separate chaining so I can proceed with my project or not. Oh and I am not required to rehash the table if it goes beyond the capacity.

Comment: This is separate chaining, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists. It qualifies as long as the array contains only the head nodes of the lists.

Comment: With separate chaining, you don't have to.. if 2 keys produce the same hashcode, then add them to the list under the same bucket / cell in the hash table.